# " No such file or directory" error when calling `os.mkdir` on WSL

Tags: python, path, operating-system, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

My laptop's main system is Windows, but it has also Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) installed. When I started to write code in python installed on WSL (Connect to WSL option in VSCode), it turned out that `os.mkdir` doesn't work as expected:

```
import os
print(os.uname()[0]) # 'Linux'
path = os.path.join("New", "2023") # path = "New/2023"
os.mkdir(path)
```

raises `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'New/2023'`.

How can I fix it? For more context: this is part of project when I need to automate creation of some new directories and save generated files to them and it must be OS independent because some users use Windows and some Linux.

Comment: `os.mkdir` doesn't work recursively. If you want to create both the `New` and `2023` directory, call `os.makedirs`

Comment: Do you mean `New` (directory) exists in the current directory, and you still get error ?

Comment: @Philippe no, `New` didn't exist - the accepted answer is correct, I just wasn't aware that `os.mkdir` doesn't create nested dirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested directories (on any *OS*), use [[Python.Docs]: os.makedirs(name, mode=0o777, exist_ok=False)](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) which states (**emphasis** is mine):

> **Recursive directory creation** function. Like [mkdir()](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkdir), but **makes all intermediate-level directories** needed to contain the leaf directory.

Of course, the goal could be also achieved using *mkdir*, but there should be one call for each directory (from outer to inner) in the path that doesn't exist, which is pretty much what *makedirs* does.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that it had something to do with working on WSL, not simply use of wrong function